# ef core - how to copy tables from one schema to other with many-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I have tables and mappings in my master schema, and I need to recreate them when I create another schema. I don't know what is the best approach, but now I do it this way:

```
            var permissions = context.Permissions.ToList();//master context
            var roles = context.TenantRoles.ToList();

            var permRoles = context.RolePermissions.ToList();
            using (var tenantContext = new TenantContext(newTenant.Id.ToString()))
            {
                RelationalDatabaseCreator creator =
                    (RelationalDatabaseCreator) tenantContext.Database.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>();
                creator.CreateTables();
                tenantContext.TenantUsers.Add(new TenantUser {UserId = user.Id});
                //tenantContext.Permissions.AddRange(permissions);
                //tenantContext.TenantRoles.AddRange(roles);
                foreach (var role in roles)
                {
                    tenantContext.TenantRoles.Add(new Role {Name = role.Name, CanBeDeleted = role.CanBeDeleted});
                }

                foreach (var permission in permissions)
                {
                    tenantContext.Permissions.Add(new Permission {Name = permission.Name});
                }
                foreach (var map in permRoles)
                {
                    tenantContext.RolePermissions.Add(new RolePermission
                    {
                        Permission = tenantContext.Permissions.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Name == map.Permission.Name),
                        Role = tenantContext.TenantRoles.FirstOrDefault(r=>r.Name == map.Role.Name)
                    });

                }
                tenantContext.SaveChanges();

            }
```

On `SaveChanges()` I get this exception:

> "The property 'RoleId' on entity type 'RolePermission' has a temporary value. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property."

If I create mappings manually(via service that creates roles, permissions and maps them), everything works fine, so I guess it's not because of many-to-many relationship. `Role`, `Permission` and `RolePermission` classes are:

```
public class Permission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<RolePermission> RolePermissions { get; set; }
}
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<RolePermission> RolePermissions { get; set; }
    public List<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public bool CanBeDeleted { get; set; }
}
public class RolePermission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
    public int PermissionId { get; set; }
    public Permission Permission { get; set; }
}
```

And OnModelCreating

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(SchemaName);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TestEntity>().ToTable("TestEntity", SchemaName);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Document>().ToTable("Documents", SchemaName);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Roles", SchemaName);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Permission>().ToTable("Permissions", SchemaName);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TenantUser>().ToTable("TenantUsers", SchemaName);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
            .HasKey(bc => new { bc.RoleId, bc.TenantUserId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Role)
            .WithMany(b => b.UserRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.RoleId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.TenantUser)
            .WithMany(c => c.UserRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.TenantUserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().ToTable("UserRole", SchemaName);

        modelBuilder.Entity<RolePermission>()
            .HasKey(bc => new { bc.RoleId, bc.PermissionId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<RolePermission>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Role)
            .WithMany(b => b.RolePermissions)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.RoleId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<RolePermission>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Permission)
            .WithMany(c => c.RolePermissions)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.PermissionId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<RolePermission>().ToTable("RolePermissions", SchemaName);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

What is the best way to copy tables with relationships and why I get this error?

Comment: As the exception message says: you have to configure the primary keys `RoleId` (and `PermissionId`) as auto -generated. (Seems you didn't).

Answer (score 0):

You also need to use `tenantContext.SaveChanges()` after you have added Roles and Permissions.Otherwise the added data will not be detected when you add `RolePermissions` using EF core.

```
foreach (var role in roles)
{
    tenantContext.TenantRoles.Add(new Role { Name = role.Name, CanBeDeleted = role.CanBeDeleted });
}
tenantContext.SaveChanges();

foreach (var permission in permissions)
{
    tenantContext.Permissions.Add(new Permission { Name = permission.Name });
}
tenantContext.SaveChanges();

foreach (var map in permRoles)
{
    tenantContext.RolePermissions.Add(new RolePermission
    {
        Permission = tenantContext.Permissions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == map.Permission.Name),
        Role = tenantContext.TenantRoles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == map.Role.Name)
    });

}
tenantContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: No, this isn't necessary. EF will figure out the correct insert order and copy auto-generated PK values to FKs.